# Correct nesting of apostrophe's/quotation marks in html/php statement

Tags: php, html

So im trying to make it possible for a user to select a file from a list and then delete the file from the server.
I know there are alot of safety concerns that I am neglecting here but I really just need to get a basic version of this to work for now.
So following up on some other threads here is the linkby which u select a file to delete:

```
echo '<a href="delete.php?file=ebooks/'.$name.'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')">Delete</a>';
```

My problem is that where I ad the variable $name to the link it breaks my nesting of quotation marks, escaping them doesn't work since that just renders it as a string "$name" and not a variable.
Can anyone please give me or help me to see what the correct way is to write this statement? 
thanks

Comment: Does `$name` contain quotation marks?

Comment: Which is the problematic `$name` value?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap $name in urlencode():

```
echo '<a href="delete.php?file=ebooks/'.urlencode($name).'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')">Delete</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use **[Heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)** for complex strings (such as HTML):

```
echo <<<HTML
<a href="delete.php?file=ebooks/{$name}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
    Delete
</a>
HTML;
```

No need to escape quotes, no need to end the string for variables. Simple and looks good.